# Is clrs really needed to be a computer scientist

Tags: algorithms, books

I want to dive in alghorithms and data structures and maybe AI this year. When I searched on internet everybody was recommending to read clrs. But I found it very complicated, because of the amount and the level of math in it. Is reading clrs really important to be a true computer scientist. If yes, how it can be easier to accomplish.
Note: I started reading Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++, but I'm planning to read other books also.

Comment: *Reading* won't help a lot, *working with* is what you should do. I'm afraid that algorithms textbooks don't come lighter in math than CLRS, so you'll want to brush up your mathematics.

Comment: Any scientist (computer or otherwise) should have a decent math background. The math in clrs is not really that heavy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be a computer scientist you need to be able to reason abstractly.  The reasoning expected in CLRS is an example.  You can find books with titles such as *Discrete Mathematics* that will help with some of the prerequisite material, and with some of the reasoning strategies.